# What is difference between setMaxResults and setFetchSize in org.hibernate.Query?

Tags: java, hibernate

What is difference between `setMaxResults` and `setFetchSize` in org.hibernate.Query? I just can no get it =)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`setMaxResults` is the same as `LIMIT` in SQL-  you are *setting the maximum number of rows you want* returned.  This is a very common use case of course.

`setFetchSize` is about *optimization*, which can change *how* Hibernate goes about sending the results to the caller (example: buffered, in different size chunks). 
`setFetchSize` is NOT implemented by all database drivers.

Comment: Please note that hibernate basically 'ignores' this setting when the fetching strategy is JOIN. It will fetch *all* the rows and afterwards truncate the in-memory results. You will notice when you see this warning: `WARN HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!`

Answer (score 48):

`setMaxResults` limits the number of results the query will ever get.

`setFetchSize` tells the jdbc driver how many rows to return in one chunk, for large queries.  Say you want 1000 rows.  If you set the fetch size to 100, the db will return 100, then another 100 when you want more, and so on.  `setFetchSize` will do nothing if your driver does not support it.

Comment: if my `select *` criteria query yields 1 million results: `criteria.list().length()`, will adding `criteria.setMaxResults(1).list().length` still return the 1 million rows, but then take only 1? I'm confused about the efficiency of `setMaxResults`. Thanks

Comment: @KevinMeredith, I'm on journey to find that out myself. My suspicion is that as developers we may need to set the Fetch Size ourselves as tuning for the specific database driver...?

Answer (score 13):

For example, if the table has 100 records, then

```
criteria.setMaxResults(25);
```

will only fetch 25 records out of 100 records, and

```
criteria.setFetchSize(20);
```

will fetch 20 records at each time until it reads all 100 records from the table.

Comment: Since your answer doesn't provide an explanation it'd be nice if you could propose the examples as edit to existing ones.