# org.hibernate.Criteria.setFetchSize() doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the below code and trying to limit the number of records retrieved. (LIMIT), but i always get all the rows. I see forums recommending me to use Query, but is not possible to achieve it using criteria ?

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Application.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.gt("lastModifiedOn", applicationLastRunTime))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("lead", false))
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("lastModifiedOn"));
criteria.setFetchSize(40);
criteria.list()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use:

```
public Criteria setMaxResults(int maxResults)
Set a limit upon the number of objects to be retrieved.
Parameters:
maxResults - the maximum number of results
Returns:
this (for method chaining)

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Application.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.gt("lastModifiedOn", applicationLastRunTime))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("lead", false))
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("lastModifiedOn"));
criteria.setMaxResults(40);
criteria.list()
```

more info: [What is difference between setMaxResults and setFetchSize in org.hibernate.Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087728/what-is-difference-between-setmaxresults-and-setfetchsize-in-org-hibernate-query)