# Hibernate : Criteria ignoring fetchSize parameter and fetching more rows than asked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I have a search function written using Criteria. FOr paginated search, I get from front-end the firstResult and fetchSize as the parameter. Unfortunately, Criteria is ignoring them and returning a huge list(around 1000 rows) when asked only for 20 rows. What is going wrong?

Code :

```
  System.out.println("Fetch size is "+fetchSize);
        System.out.println("First result is "+firstResult);
Criteria andCriteria = session.createCriteria(Host.class);
            Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();
            if((studentSearchHistory.getCity()!=null) && (!(studentSearchHistory.getCity().isEmpty()))) {
                and.add(Restrictions.ilike("city", studentSearchHistory.getCity()));
            }
//Other search conditions
    andCriteria.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
    andCriteria.setFirstResult(firstResult);
    andCriteria.add(and);
    hostList.addAll(andCriteria.list());
  if(hostList != null){
     System.out.println("Host list size is "+hostList.size());
   }
```

Output :

```
Fetch size is 10
First result is 0
Host list size is 1003
```

What am I doing wrong? THank you.

Comment: try `criteria.setMaxResults(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should using `setMaxResults` here.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087728/what-is-difference-between-setmaxresults-and-setfetchsize-in-org-hibernate-query) is a comparation for these two methods.

Answer (score 2):

`fetchSize` **is not related to the number of record exported by the query**. It is related to the number of record fetched.

You need to use [`setMaxResults`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)) to limit the number of record retrieved by hibernate.

> Set the **maximum number of rows to retrieve**. If not set, there is no limit to the number of rows retrieved.

[`setFetchSize`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFetchSize(int)) is related only to how internally hibernate fetch group of records (is a sort of cache).

> Set a fetch size for the underlying JDBC query.

And from the description of [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)):

> Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database when more rows are needed for ResultSet objects genrated by this Statement. If the value specified is zero, then the hint is ignored. The default value is zero.