# Hibernate criteria.setFetchSize is not working as expected

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on performance improvement. We are using both Hibernate Criteria and Named Query to retrieve data from database.
In our application we are retrieving more rows from database and performing some Java logic so I want to fetch more rows at a time from Database to avoid network trips to database.
As the default fetch size for oracle database is 10 I have set this to 400 to the criteria object as below.

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Phone.class);
crit.setFetchSize(400);
```

I did not notice any improvement in the response times.
I have noticed improvement when I set the higher fetch size on NamedQuery as below.

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("getPhoneList");
query.setFetchSize(400);
```

Any suggestions why `crit.setFetchSize(400);` is not working as expected.

Comment: You can try to inspect the TCP traffic to the db,  using Wireshark, for example, in order to try to understand what goes on before and after you set the fetch size (to understand how, if at all, setFetchSize influences the "network trips").

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the issue, and it seems that `crit.setFetchSize(400);` is not limiting the returned result. However, There's another useful method `setMaxResults(int maxResults)` that will limit the return results from your DB.

Take a look at the next image from Hibernate API:

[image]

I have marked in red the method that is not doing the apparently requested behavior, maybe it's related to the second method within the red rectangle.

Take a look at the green rectangle with the method that will limit your results from DB:

[image]

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Phone.class).setMaxResults(400);
List<Phone> list = crit.list();
```

The maximum size of list will be 400.

Comment: setMaxResults(400) will restrict the total number of result rows. My requirements is not restrict the result rows. The data from database is returned to application server in chunks(default size of 10 rows for oracle). When my query is returning large number of rows there will be more network trips to database. I want to set the chunk size to higher like 400 so that number of network trips to database are minimized.  setFetchSize() should give the result rows in larger chunks but I am not seeing it working as expected in my code.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to the following post could also be an explanation for why the **setFetchSize** is not applying

[What is difference between setMaxResults and setFetchSize in org.hibernate.Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087728/what-is-difference-between-setmaxresults-and-setfetchsize-in-org-hibernate-query)

the second part where he talks about database drivers, there jazzinthemorning says:

"*setFetchSize is NOT implemented by all database drivers*"